# Unity Physics.Raycast give false positive while using layer mask

Tags: unity

I'm very new to Unity so please excuse my question if this sounds very basic to you.

I'm following various tutorials and I have a small question regarding `Physics.Raycast`:

```
if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) {
        // check ground hit first
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, LayerMask.GetMask("Ground"))) {
            Debug.Log("[PlayerMotion]: Hit" + hit.collider.name + " " + hit.point);
            agent.SetDestination(hit.point);
        }
}
```

Here, even tough I expressively set the layer mask to `"Ground"`, I still get a hit with the Player game object itself (the ground hit is working fine). I thought ok maybe I put the "Ground" layer as well on the player by mistake but I checked several times and it's not the case.

I'm attaching a gif so you can see what's the issue exactly

[image]

There's an easy by checking the `collider.name` but I still find it odd that the `Raycast` gives me a false positive with the player hit. Any idea what's going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are not passing your layer mask into the `maxDistance` param.

The signature of `Physics.Raycast` (the one that accepts a ray as the first argument) is

```
public static bool Raycast(Ray ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction = QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal);
```

Notice that the third parameter is `maxDistance` and not `layerMask`.
In other words, use

```
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, LayerMask.GetMask("Ground"))
```

instead of

```
Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, LayerMask.GetMask("Ground"))
```

This is a common mistake as `LayerMask.GetMask` returns an `int` which will be implicitly cast into a float and thrown into `maxDistance` instead of `layerMask`.